# High School Algebra Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3y^2}$ has to be equal to a negative real number. The absolute value of x,y has to be equal to or more than 2. Find values for x,y.

My son was asked this question in his High School Algebra class.

There seem to be 2 schools of thought here:

1. There is no solution
2. Some value of x (perfect square) and taking the negative square root.

Any input would be great.

Nimish

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's a product of two nonnegative numbers, hence it's nonnegative.

Comment: "Some value of x (perfect square) and taking the negative square root." -- This is basically entirely incorrect. You cannot "take the negative square root." $\sqrt{x}$ is definitionally a nonnegative number (provided $x \ge 0$). If you had a $\pm$ out front, as in e.g. the quadratic formula, there is a chance to take a negative root. If you had $-\sqrt x$, then sure you'd have a nonpositive number. But the only circumstance in which $\sqrt x$ gives a negative number in this context is either using a very nonstandard definition or totally misunderstanding what this means.

Comment: The comment of @PrincessEev assumes that the problem's background is *Real Analysis*, rather than *Complex Analysis*.  This is a very reasonable assumption, given that this is a high school problem, and no mention of Complex Analysis is made.  If Complex Analysis is allowed, then the problem, as posted, needs to be edited.  For one thing, the problem's presentation suggests that $~\sqrt{x}~$ is unambiguously defined.  ...see next comment

Comment: While this true in Real Analysis, where $~x~$ must be $~\geq 0,~$ and it is understood that $~\sqrt{x}~$ is $~\geq 0,~$ in Complex Analysis there is no such convention, so the problem solver does not know which square root of $~x~$ to take.  Further, the problem should explicitly state that the problem's background is Complex Analysis, rather than Real Analysis.  One consequence of such a statement is that $~x,y~$ do not have to be Real numbers to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: @user2661923 I am a novice. So pardon my basic question. So just clarifying: If we take complex analysis as the background, then taking the negative sqrt(x) is a reasonable assumption? Even if x is a real number?

Comment: Even if you use complex analysis to put meaning into square rooting a negative, you would end up with an complex number in some situations because the solution of the inequality $|x| \geq 2$ is $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, \infty)$, and plugging in negative numbers for $x$ results in complex numbers. Same goes for $y$. Note that $y^2$ is always positive given the conditions for $y$. The square root of a positive number is positive, but for $x$ being negative, you would end up with a complex number. For instance, $\sqrt{-2}$ is a complex number and not a real number.

Comment: In the American education system, teachers usually teach "you can't square root a negative" or something like that. Not trying to assume your son lives in the US, but I don't know of a high school anywhere in this world that would teach something like, "In complex analysis, the square root is ambiguous because you can write it in terms of an exponential and logarithm and logarithms are multivalued for complex numbers." In your case, I don't think you should worry about complex analysis. Even using complex analysis leads to the same answer, anyways.

Comment: @Accelerator "Even using complex analysis leads to the same answer, anyways." I disagree.  It is not required that either $~x~$ or $~y~$ be real numbers, only that the following expression be a negative real number: $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3y^2}.$$  One satisfying solution is $$\sqrt{x} = 20e^{i\pi/4}, ~y^2 = \frac{20}{3} e^{-3i\pi/4}.$$  Of course, this still leaves the problem of deciding (for example) when $~x = e^{i\pi/2},~$ which value to use for $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x}.~$ You also have the difficulty that Complex Analysis is not explicitly specified as the background of the Math problem.

Comment: @user2661923 The OP says the absolute values of $x$ and $y$ are equal to $2$ or more. I was interpreting $x$ and $y$ as some real numbers, but I guess $x$ could equal something like $-3i$ if we really want to be technical and that my argument fails. In any case, I don't see a reason to go down the complex analysis rabbit hole nor a reason to keep insisting some crazy examples like $20 e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: To Nimish Joshi : in answer to your comment/question : First of all, the requirement is not that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x}~$ be negative, but rather  (re my last comment) that the fraction evaluate to a negative (real) number.  Second, no, in Complex Analysis, when $~x~$ is a complex number (that may or may not be real), you can't assume that the $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x}~$ is unambiguous.  A Complex Analysis convention must be agreed upon first.  Last, you can't assume that the problem's background is Complex Analysis without an explicit corresponding specification.

Comment: @Accelerator I was simply making up an **unusual** example to show that a satisfying $~(x,y)~$ does not require that either $~x~$ or $~y~$ are real.  Further, my motive for *assuming* a background of Complex Analysis is that absent such an assumption, the problem as posed becomes *nonsensical*.

Comment: Might I suggest that since the problem specifically mentions "real" numbers (implying an awareness of non-real numbers has already been established) that perhaps we could dispense with wild interpretations of $\sqrt x$ and instead use a very simple interpretation of $y^2$? Namely $x = 9, \sqrt x = 3, y = i$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $~|y|~$ must be $~\geq 2.~$  Also, the background of the problem must be Complex Analysis, in order for the fraction to evaluate to a negative real.  However, in Complex Analysis, you can not assert that $~\sqrt{9} = 3,~$ without specifying some preliminary convention.  One plausible convention, that must be stated, is that if $~z = re^{i\alpha},~$ then the *principal argument* of $~z~$ is $~\beta \in (-\pi,\pi],~$ such that $~\beta \equiv \alpha \pmod{2\pi}.~$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then, you could have the added convention that the *principal square root* is $~\sqrt{r} \times e^{i\beta/2}.~$  Without any explicit statements of such conventions, this is a lot to assume.

Comment: @user2661923 - Complex *Analysis* is a middle level course for an Baccalaureate mathematics degree, but Complex *numbers* are a subject of high school algebra, such as is mentioned in the very title of this post. This problem can be solved with only the most basic knowledge of complex numbers, which is clearly the most appropriate approach in this situation. As for your comment about $\sqrt 9$. There is **no one**, not grasping at straws while trying to defend an untenable position, who would bat an eye at saying $\sqrt 9 = 3$.